# A question about the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let the dihedral group $D_n$ be given by elements $a$ of order $n$ and $b$ of order $2$, where $ba = a^{-1}b.$

(a) Show that $a^{-m}= a^{n-m}$ for all integers $m.$

Definition: Let $n$ greater than or equal to $3$ be an integer. The group of rigid motions of a regular n-gon is called the $nth$ **dihedral group**, denoted by $D_n.$

I'm having trouble showing (a). Any hints or thoughts will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know for an elements $x\in G$, $x^mx^n=x^{m+n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $$a^{b+c} = a^ba^c$$

And recall that, since the order of $a$ is given to be $n$, we know that $a^n = e$.

Applying that here gives us:

$$a^{n-m}=a^na^{-m}=ea^{-m}=a^{-m}$$

Comment: okay I was just about to ask if we were not considering the given orders in this case. Now I understand. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, Candy.

Comment: As amWhy has pointed out, this doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that your group is dihedral.

Answer (score 1):

$a^{n-m}=a^n.a^{-m}=ea^{-m}=a^{-m}$